# How do you enable short tags for PHP in Microsoft WebMatrix?

Tags: php, webmatrix

How do you enable short tags (i.e. `<?` and `<?=`) when using WebMatrix as your web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short open tags is a property of [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) config file... Do a simple script like this: `<?php phpinfo();` and run it to see the location of php.ini file...

Comment: Thanks it was at C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v5.2\php.ini.  I turned on short_open_tag

Comment: What's confusing is why including "ini_set('short_open_tag', 1);" in the code doesn't work. This normally works to help portability, but didn't work for me in WebMatrix. Good thing the global setting is easy enough to change.

Comment: Edward, not all the available options can be changed using ini_set. Ready more details in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: jaminto, Edward: I really advise you to not do the use of the short_open_tags turned on, this will be removed in future versions.